# Sorting lines with regex in perl

Tags: regex, perl, sorting, file-io, lines

I am trying to read a log file and write all the error logs to a new file. I must also keep track of how many errors there are and the number of messages in general.  I must assume that the logs will be broken up onto multiple lines, so I have been using regex and series a variables to search for all possibilities and write to the appropriate file. 
My file handles are: FILE, ERRORFILE, and SUCCESSFILE.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $totalcount = 0;
my $errorcount = 0;
my $log        = "s"; # $log controls what what should be written where,
                      # incase it doesn't start with code.
                      # "s" = SuccessFile, "e" = ErrorFile

my $logStart   = "y"; # used with m/^I/ or m/^E/ instead of full code
                      # incase the code is broken into pieces.
my $dash = 0;

while (<FILE>) {
    $dash += () = $_ =~ m/-/g;   # can't use tr/// because it counts at compile
    if ( $dash lt 25 ) { next; } # this line skips "---Begin <Repository>---"
    elsif ( m/[a-zA-Z <>]/ && $dash lt 25 ) { next; }
    elsif ( $dash >= 26 ) { last; }    #Ends loop at "---End <Repository>---"

    if ( m/^I/ && $logStart eq "y" ) {
        $log      = "s";
        $logStart = "n";
        $totalcount++;
        next;
    }                                  #Ignores nonerror logs
    elsif ( m/^E/ && $logStart eq "y" ) {
        chomp $_;
        print ERRORFILE "$_";
        $errorcount++;
        $totalcount++;
        $log      = "e";
        $logStart = "n";
    }
    elsif (m/ \.\n$/) {                 #End of log

        if ( $log eq "s" ) { $logStart = "y"; next; }
        print ERRORFILE "$_\n" if $log eq "e";
        $logStart = "y";
    }
    else {   #line doesn't start with code or end in " .\n"

        chomp $_;
        print ERRORFILE "$_" if $log eq "e";
        next if $log eq "s";
    }
}

print "\nThere are $errorcount error logs.\n";
print "There are $totalcount logs in the full log file.\n";
```

I know that the non-error logs start with I00020036 and the errors start with E03020039.  Both end in " .\n"

```
---------- Begin <Load Repository> ---------------
I00020036: Loaded C:\Documents and       Settings\dorja03\Desktop\DSMProduct\external\etpki\Linux_2.4_x86\redistrib\readme.txt  into \DSM R11\external\etpki\Linux_2.4_x86\redistrib\readme.txt .
E03020039: Unable to load C:\Documents and     Settings\dorja03\Desktop\DSMProduct\external\etpki\Linux_2.4_x86\redistrib\etpki_install_lib.sh  into \DSM R11\external\etpki\Linux_2.4_x86\redistrib\etpki_install_lib.sh . Text file contains invalid characters .
---------- End <Load Repository> ---------------
```

I have been running a test sample with two lines. If the error comes up first, it will print it to the error file, along with the non-error log, and on the same line.  If the non-error goes first, it doesn't recognize the error.

Is this because I'm using m// wrong or something else entirely?

Edit: Test input has been added. I also added the code to skip the header and footer.

Test output: If the non-error comes first, there are 0 errors and 1 log total.
             If the non-error comes first, there is 1 error and 1 log total.

If this worked, it should have said there was 1 error and 2 logs.  It also would have only printed the error to the ERRORFILE.

Comment: Could you please post a sample test case and its output?

Comment: Please use use strict; and use warnings. I see ERRORFILE along with the print, is it a bare-word filehandle? Please use three argument filehandles.

Comment: Looks like you'll benefit from setting `local $/ = ".\n";`.

Comment: There is not enough information to answer your question. And it is rather hard to tell what the question is. Make a runnable code sample with input and output and explain what output you really wanted.

Answer (score 2):

This won't answer why your code isn't working, but here's how I would approach the problem:

- Since the logs can span over multiple lines, modify the default line-by-line behavior by tweaking [`$/`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).
- Use appropriate data structures to filter the errors from non-errors. This will also allow you to defer printing till later.

The code would then look something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %logs;
local $/ = " .\n";

while ( <> ) {  # Now $_ is the full (multi-line) log

    next if /--- Begin/;  # Skip if /Begin/
    last if /--- End/;    # Stop processing if /End/

    if ( m/^I/ ) {
        push @{ $logs{nonerror} }, $_;
    }

    if ( m/^E/ ) {
        push @{ $logs{error} }, $_;
    }
}

printf "There are %d error logs\n.", scalar @{ $logs{error} // [] } ;
printf "There are %d logs in the full logfile.\n",
         @{$logs{error} // []} + @{$logs{nonerror} // []};
```

---

Things I like about this approach:

- Perl takes care of deciding when each log message ends (eliminates the `$logStart` variable altogether).
- The logic is much easier to extend.
- The `while` loop is dedicated to processing the log file (no need to `++` anything).
- Use of sensibly-labeled data structures instead of temporary variables makes for easier code maintenance.

Comment: I like how clean it looks, but it only counts the error if its 2nd, and it says I can't use an undefined array reference at the last line.

Comment: @CDynomite : Changed the `elsif` to `if` to fix the first bug, and made use of the "defined-or" operator (`//`) to address the second. If your version of Perl doesn't support `//`, just initialize the 'error' and 'nonerror' hash keys with empty array references before the `while` loop.

Comment: I figured it out. It had to do with the scope of $logstart. Thanks for the help, I'll try your way later when I have the time.

Answer (score 0):

To make a formal answer, I scrapped this code and replaced it.  I instead fed the file into var with a delimiter, then just split it into an array.  It was much easier and cleaner.  I don't however have the code anymore due to a lost flashdrive.